# Dreamweaver Template (dwt) and library plugins for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, dreamweaver

Does anyone know if there is a plugin for Visual Studio which adds dwt and library functionality like you get in Dreamweaver. I much prefer using Visual Studio but need to keep the dwt format for external developers.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I believe Visual Studio will play with .dwt just fine as the MS Expression Web editor can edit/use .dwt as well. You can always use DW or Expression to layout .dwt, then code in VS.

DWT is just a way to comment an area for global updating when saving.